# WPF DataGrid with multiple columns in group row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping, hierarchical-data

I am trying to work with native WPF DataGrid control to show hierarchical data. Similar to the structure of data shown in image below (ignore the cosmetics) where :

1. GroupRows have same number of columns as the main grid.
2. Group row do not repeat column headers for every group, instead just flexible enough to show a summary in each column.
3. Expanding the column headers should resize all the rows in the grid including group row.

Reading up some examples I can see there is option to define a header template for each group row but I am not sure how get above points work together.

I have stumbled upon some implementations of reusable wpf controls that have heavy codebase I am reluctant to inherit just to get some minimalistic features.

Any help or pointers would be very useful.

[image: Hierarchical data view]

Comment: I appreciate your will for minimalism and avoiding the use of large pieces of code if you only need specific features, but if your goal is speed and ease of implementation, using a pre-built and widely tested control will likely be easier.